# How to set the div and its children to responsive mode without using an iframe in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm creating a page where I have a parent div which encapsulates multiple child divs from different components in a NextJs project.

I have a preview option where my customers can preview their changes in mobile and desktop view.

I'm able to switch to mobile view using iframe. I want to achieve this without using an iframe.

Even though I change the parent div max width, because the rest of components have  `sm` `md` `lg` `xl` which are taking the values from the view port instead of the parent div I'm unable to solve it.

What should be the approach to solve this?

Comment: Tell them to open the devtools. Or implement something like this: https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes Don't use an iframe.

Comment: This is tough.  You could try [resizing the window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeBy#creating_and_resizing_an_external_window)?  Tailwind allows you to [modify the breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens) but I'm pretty sure that can only be done at build-time and not dynamically while the app is running.

Answer (score 2):

Media breakpoints allows you to change content appearance based on viewport size. Tailwind's media variants like `md:`, `lg:` etc based on them. In order to change content based on parent's size you should use [CSS Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). Be aware - they are not production ready - about [75% browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries) (actual at December 2022)

> Container queries allow us to look at a container size and apply styles to the contents based on the size of their container rather than the viewport or other device characteristics.

Tailwind has official plugin which may help you with it. Install it configure within `tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ],
}
```

You need to add `@container` class to a parent container and use size modifiers on element you need like `@md:bg-blue-500`.

```html
<div class="@container max-w-full resize-x overflow-auto">

    <div class="p-16 @md:bg-blue-500 bg-amber-400">
        Resize me
    </div>

</div>
```

This way element should be yellow unless container size is bigger than 28rem and it will become blue no matter viewport size

Produced CSS is

```css
@container (min-width: 28rem) {
  .\@md\:bg-blue-500 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(59 130 246 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }
}
```

Check other modifiers [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-container-queries#configuration). Please note `md:flex` and `@md:flex` are different sizes which may confuse at first

`@containers` supports labels so you can name containers and specify different CSS for them. Let's say you have reusable component (common situation) you include within loop

```html
<div class="@4xl/aside:bg-red-500 @3xl/primary:bg-yellow-500">
</div>
```

So within `@container/aside` element your card will be red after `@4xl (56rem)` size, while within `@container/primary` - yellow after `@3xl (48rem)`.

```html
<div class="@container/aside">
    <div class="@4xl/aside:bg-red-500 @3xl/primary:bg-yellow-500">
        YELLOW
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@container/aside">
    <div class="@4xl/aside:bg-red-500 @3xl/primary:bg-yellow-500">
        RED
    </div>
</div>
```

As I said it's not production ready. The way you want to handle unsupported browsers is up to you. First one - use [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/container-query-polyfill). Just add

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/container-query-polyfill@1/dist/container-query-polyfill.modern.js"></script>
```

and it should be enough. However read full docs to improve user experience. I didn't fully tested it myself so cannot guarantee it is 100% solution

Second way is to check does browser supports container queries or not. You can check it via JS

```js
if (!("container" in document.documentElement.style)) {
    console.log('No support')

    // Do something in that case
}
```

Another way - via CSS [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) rule

```css
@supports (container-type:inline-size) {
    /** Container queries supported */
}
```

Tailwind has `supports:` variant for that needs so something like this would work

```html
<div class="supports-[container-type:inline-size]:hidden">
    Your browser does not support container queries
    Maybe show iframe element as backup (?)
</div>

<div class="supports-[container-type:inline-size]:block hidden">
    Here is my cool feature which will be hidden if browser does not supports container queries
</div>
```

I've created this [demo playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EC27RQIhZT?size=1238x1318) without polyfill to check different cases depends on container and window size plus different types of container and browser support

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this can be adding a `w-screen` to parent `div`.
Use `w-screen` to make an element span the entire width of the viewport.

[Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to access children in Tailwindcss is to class `[&>]` to the parent div. For example, let's say you have 5 child divs. If you want to give an attribute to the last of them `[&>div:last-child]:bg-blue-500` , if you want to make it responsive, `max-md:[&>div:last-child]:bg-blue-500` you have to express. I have prepared a demo for you to make it more meaningful, you can check it from the link below. If you expand the preview screen on the right a little, you will see that the colors have disappeared. I hope it can solve your problem.

[Demo Code](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wtip060v8h)

Comment: At this point, rather write vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant complelty

```
<div class="max-w-full sm:max-w-full md:max-w-3xl lg:max-w-4xl xl:max-w-5xl">
    <div class="text-sm sm:text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl xl:text-2xl"> 
        For small screen sizes
    </div>
    <div class="flex-sm-row sm:flex-row md:flex-col lg:flex-col xl:flex-col">
        <div class="w-sm sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/5">
            This for  50% width
        </div>
        <div class="w-sm sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/5">
            This for  50% width
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden sm:hidden md:block lg:block xl:block">
        For large and extra-large screen sizes.
    </div>
</div>
```